# rails joins conditions as hash

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Course.find(:all, :group =>:id, :order => 'updated_at DESC', :joins=> :students  :conditions => { :students =>  { :first_name=>"John", :status => 1}})

looking this query, passing the conditions as a hash, there is a way to:

- construct a where :first_name not null?
- construct a where :first_name != "John"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively, there is not a way of which I am aware.  There is [ar-extensions](http://github.com/zdennis/ar-extensions) which extends the finders with many things, including negating.

```
:conditions => { :students =>  { :first_name_not => "John"}}
:conditions => { :students =>  { :first_name_not => nil}}
```

Fair warning, last update I see for it is a year ago and support is limited to postgre, mysql and sqlite.  This is the only active project I am aware of that extends activerecord in this way.  Thoughtbot had [squirrel](http://github.com/thoughtbot/squirrel), which you might be able to find some active forks for.